# Use HTML element attribute as rails form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a html.erb page.

Have some dynamic attributes of my span

HTML:

```
<span>something<span>
```

jQuery:

```
$('span').attr('data-x', function(){})
```

Ruby:

```
<%= form_for @blah do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :x_value, value: ?? %>
<% end %>
```

So basically the span attribute 'data-x' will change from time to time based on the function, and I have a button set up, if I click the button, I want the value of the 'data-x' attribute be submitted by form helper to my database column "x_value".

How can I do that? Thank y'all!

After getting the idea from Inf, I got this part done. 
Get the value of the attribute in my js file:

`var valueX = $('span').attr('data-x')`

Add an ID for the hidden field in my erb file:

`<%= f.hidden_field :x_value, :id=>"columnX" %>`

Then assign the id with valueX in my js file:

`$("#columnX").val(valueX)`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Also checkout: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks!

Comment: When the data-x changes, change the hidden field value, too...

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, and I will confirm the change with the button clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1. You can update hidden field on form submit, for example:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $('input[type="hidden"]').val($('span').attr('data-x'));
  return true;
});
```

Option 2. Update hidden field together with span:

```
var value = function(){};
$('span').attr('data-x', value);
$('input[type="hidden"]').val(value);
```

Comment: Yes, this works, I tried use this idea with something like this
`<%= f.hidden_field :x_value, :id => "hiddenX" %>`
and use Jquery to assign the value to this ID and it did export the data to the database. Thank you!